# Wordpress custom post type dropdown list on another post type in editor

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-post-type

So I have created a custom post type, let's call it `actors`, and another one called `movies`. So, when I edit a movie I want to have a dropdown list with all my actors post, select one and output that ID in the frontend to use with another function. It is doable? How do I do it

TEST CODE:

```html
    <?php 
  $data_terms = get_terms('test_post', array(
            'orderby'    => 'count',
            'hide_empty' => 0,
            'parent'=> 4 // You need the Id of the parent actors taxonomy
             ) );
?>
<select>
     <?php foreach($data_terms as $term):  ?>
         <option>
             <?php echo $term->name; echo $term->ID ?>
         </option>
     <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I have the code to create custom posts, I can add the meta in code or ACF. What I really want to know is how do i get the 'actors' in my meta to create a dropdown and how do i output the selected one's ID

Comment: Why test_post and no actors?

Comment: because that's the post I created. It's the same as actors, nothing different, just the name and id

Comment: If you do not want your question to be off topic, get your initial question again and post it. Then, below that question post the code. Now you replaced the question and for somenone who has not seen our conversation it doesnt make any sense.

Comment: I did not modify any word of the question... That is still the original question.

Comment: What can I say... Put a title maybe EDIT or TEST CODE above the code. And please dont be aggresive to the moderators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everything in PHP, to create a list of objects, you have to follow these steps.

Firstly, get the data.

```
<?php 
        $data_terms = get_terms('your_custom_taxonomy', array(
            'orderby'    => 'count',
            'hide_empty' => 0,
            'parent'=>13 // You need the Id of the parent actors taxonomy
             ) );
?>
```

Now you can display it however you want.
You want a list. So:

```
<select>
     <?php foreach($data_terms as $term):  ?>
         <option>
             <?php echo $term->name; echo $term->ID ?>
         </option>
     <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Now you have the ID. Ofcourse you dont want to display it, but you can pass it in a buffer and use it at will.

Hope his helped.

Comment: What code you have used so far?

Comment: From this snippet of code?

Comment: @Leonidas-Actually I am talking to "yomisimie" to show some piece of code.

Comment: I feel stupid now, it works, it shows an empty dropdown list. I think I did not put in the correct parent actors taxonomy...

Comment: @ArshadHussain I only tried this one.

Comment: To get the correct id use this: `<?php echo 'Category blog id: '.get_cat_ID(Actors) ?>` or for a custom taxonomy you need something like `<?php echo the_ID() ?>` in your actors page.

Comment: @Leonidas it echoes the ID, also I was using the correct ID, but the posts still won't show up in the dropdown.

Comment: Please, post the code you are using. Just edit your initial post. Take the script I posted and fill it with your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a custom field in wordpress.

There are articles on the wordpress codex such as [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)
(its more reading then code so havent posted the samples)

Or if you want to use a plugin then [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) is one of the ones I've used in the past

Comment: I know the bit about custom field, but how do I output the 'actor' posts if I am using ACF? With a post loop or query?

Comment: You can add customer fields in acf which you can auto wire to custom post types